# I want my url to end with details/logged-in-user/

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am creating a profile page for a project. Whenever user tries to fill in their details, i want the url trailig to be ***localhost:8002/detail/logged-in-user.username***.

Example

> ***localhost:8002/detail/dubsy***

My problem now is that whenever i edit the username in the url and provide another username that is not logged in, it still renders out the page and i don't want this.

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="signin")
def details(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    form = Details()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Details(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            detail = form.save(commit=False)
            detail.username = request.user
            detail.save()
            return redirect(success, pk=detail.pk)
    else:
        form = Details(initial={"matricno":request.user.username})
    return render(request, "details.html", {"form":form})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("details/<str:username>/", views.details, name="details"),
]
```

So my problem is that i want to prevent rendering out the page for a user who is not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to currently logged-in user to use its correct username to access details pages, you can add the logic that checks **str:username**(from url) and **username**(from session) are same.

```py
@login_required(login_url="signin")
def details(request, username):

    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    
    if user != request.user:
        # do something
        return render(request, "details.html", {'alert':'check your username'})

    form = Details()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Details(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            detail = form.save(commit=False)
            detail.username = request.user
            detail.save()
            return redirect(success, pk=detail.pk)
    else:
        form = Details(initial={"matricno":request.user.username})
    return render(request, "details.html", {"form":form})
```

Additionally if you want to prevent 'User matching query does not exist.' error raised by entering unregistered username, you can change get() to filter() like this.

```py
@login_required(login_url="signin")
def details(request, username):

    user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
    
    if user != request.user:
        # do something
        return render(request, "details.html", {'alert':'check your username'})

    form = Details()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Details(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            detail = form.save(commit=False)
            detail.username = request.user
            detail.save()
            return redirect(success, pk=detail.pk)
    else:
        form = Details(initial={"matricno":request.user.username})
    return render(request, "details.html", {"form":form})
```